# Differential operators with arbitrary functions?

Tags: reference-request, differential-operators

By Taylor expansion, one has $$f(x+t) = \sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{D^k}{k!}f(x)([x+t]-x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{(Dt)^k}{k!}f(x)$$ and hence one could say $e^{Dt}$ is translation by $t$. But this isn't a "differential operator", not [by Wikipedia's definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) My questions: in what sense is this a truly convergent "differential operator"? I have seen similar ones e.g. replace $D$ with the Laplacian; what does this mean, and why do we care about them?

Comment: Lagrange wrote $g(s+t)=\exp(t\frac{d}{dt})g(s)$ in his *Nouvelle espece de calcul*, 1772. This is a formal way to denote what in the modern science is related to the field of [$C_0$ semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup). Here is a [nice book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387984636).

Comment: @A.G. Thanks :) If you expand a little on that I would be more than happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Starting with the familiar
   $$
   e^t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}.
   $$
   We know that $e^{t+s}=e^te^s$.
2. For a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}$
   $$
   e^{At}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^nt^n}{n!}.
   $$
   What we know is the same $e^{A(t+s)}=e^{At}e^{As}$ and that it is the fundamental solution to $\dot x=Ax$. If we denote the fundamental solution by $T(t)=e^{At}$, the former property can be written as 
   $$
   T(t+s)=T(t)T(s),\qquad T(0)=I.
   $$
   Thus, the mapping $T(t)=e^{At}$ defines a [$C_0$ semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Formal_definition). Here, you can interpret $T(t)$ as the *shift along the trajectories* of $\dot x=Ax$.
3. For an abstract one-parametric $C_0$ semigroup on a Banach space $X$ we define the *generator* $A$ as (in the derivative manner) 
   $$
   Ax=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{t}(T(t)-I)x,\qquad\forall x\in X.
   $$
   If a $C_0$ semigroup is *uniformly continuous*, which means that $t\mapsto T(t)$ is continuos wrt the uniform operator topology, then there exists a bounded operator $A$ such that $T(t)=e^{At}$. It means that

   > all uniformly continuous semigroups look like exponentials of some bounded operator.
4. Consider a left translation semigroup 
   $$
   T(t)f(s)=f(s+t).
   $$
   It can be shown to be not uniformly continuous, unfortunately, but it is still quite nice in the sense that it is *strongly continuous* semigroup (i.e. wrt the strong operator topology) on $L^p$, $1\le p<\infty$. For strongly continuous semigroup it is still possible to define the generator $A$, however it is no longer bounded, but a closed operator. For the left shift semigroup the generator is the differential operator
   $$
   Af(s)=f'(s)
   $$
   defined on the Sobolev space (the space with the graph metric) $W^{1,p}$. So $A=D$, and it is tempting to write $T(t)=e^{Dt}$, but it is no longer possible, since the semigroup is not uniformly bounded. However, there are certain similarities with $e^{Dt}$ as we have seen above.

P.S. Note that all the differential operators in Wikipedia have a *finite* sum definition. It is precise the problem here: to give interpretation to the infinte series we have to go beyond the exponential.